# How to use/invoke KeyEvents from main class to use in sub class

Tags: java, call, invoke, keyevent

Okay so bascially i have these key events set up in the main class already: https://prnt.sc/jhbxz9.

what im trying to accomplish here is use these key events set in my main class so i can write a method with if/else statements under peformAction in my sub class (player) to make the player move when a key is pressed and stop moving when released. Currently all i can get it to do is consistently move in one direction till it goes off screen without the need of any keys being pressed, but i want it so that it changes velX when VK_LEFT is being pressed but i have 0 idea how to refer to the key event in my sub class without the code breaking. One last thing is that i noticed there is setKey under every key event which made me think i needed to use the setKeys, but still nothing.

Usfull screenshots if u cant be asked to read all of the code.
Player Class(sub class): http://prntscr.com/jhbx58 + http://prntscr.com/jhbxim

GameManager Class (main class): http://prntscr.com/jhbxz9

GameManager Class:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameManager extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    private int canvasWidth;
    private int canvasHeight;
    private int borderLeft;
    private int borderTop;
    private BufferedImage canvas;
    private Stage stage;
    private Enemy[] enemies;
    private Player player;
    private Goal goal;
    private Graphics gameGraphics;
    private Graphics canvasGraphics;
    private int numEnemies;
    private boolean continueGame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
// During development, you can adjust the values provided in the brackets below
// as needed. However, your code must work with different/valid combinations
// of values.
        GameManager managerObj = new GameManager(1920, 1280, 30);
    }

    public GameManager(int preferredWidth, int preferredHeight, int maxEnemies) {
        this.borderLeft = getInsets().left;
        this.borderTop = getInsets().top;
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        if (screenSize.width < preferredWidth) {
            this.canvasWidth = screenSize.width - getInsets().left - getInsets().right;
        } else {
            this.canvasWidth = preferredWidth - getInsets().left - getInsets().right;
        }
        if (screenSize.height < preferredHeight) {
            this.canvasHeight = screenSize.height - getInsets().top - getInsets().bottom;
        } else {
            this.canvasHeight = preferredHeight - getInsets().top - getInsets().bottom;
        }
        setSize(this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        Random rng = new Random(2);
        this.canvas = new BufferedImage(this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
// Create a Stage object to hold the background images
        this.stage = new Stage();
// Create a Goal object with its initial x and y coordinates
        this.goal = new Goal(this.canvasWidth / 2, Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % this.canvasHeight);
// Create a Player object with its initial x and y coordinates
        this.player = new Player(this.canvasWidth - (Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % (this.canvasWidth / 2)),
                (Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % this.canvasHeight));
// Create the Enemy objects, each with a reference to this (GameManager) object
// and their initial x and y coordinates.
        this.numEnemies = maxEnemies;
        this.enemies = new Enemy[this.numEnemies];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.numEnemies; i++) {
            this.enemies[i] = new Enemy(this, Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % (this.canvasWidth / 4),
                    Math.abs(rng.nextInt()) % this.canvasHeight);
        }
        this.gameGraphics = getGraphics();
        this.canvasGraphics = this.canvas.getGraphics();
        this.continueGame = true;
        while (this.continueGame) {
            updateCanvas();
        }
        this.stage.setGameOverBackground();
        updateCanvas();
    }

    public void updateCanvas() {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
// If the player is alive, this should move the player in the direction of the
// key that has been pressed
// Note: See keyPressed and keyReleased methods in the GameManager class.
        this.player.performAction();
// If the enemy is alive, the enemy must move towards the goal. The goal object
// is obtained
// via the GameManager object that is given at the time of creating an Enemy
// object.
// Note: The amount that the enemy moves by must be much smaller than that of
// the player above
// or else the game becomes too hard to play.
        for (int i = 0; i < this.numEnemies; i++) {
            this.enemies[i].performAction();
        }
        if ((Math.abs(this.goal.getX() - this.player.getX()) < (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2))
                && (Math.abs(this.goal.getY() - this.player.getY()) < (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth()
                / 2))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.numEnemies; i++) {
// Sets the image of the enemy to the "dead" image and sets its status to
// indicate dead
                this.enemies[i].die();
            }
// Sets the image of the enemy to the "dead" image and sets its status to
// indicate dead
            this.goal.die();
// Sets the background of the stage to the finished game background.
            this.stage.setGameOverBackground();
            this.continueGame = false;
        }
// If an enemy is close to the goal, the player and goal die
        int j = 0;
        while (j < this.numEnemies) {
            if ((Math.abs(this.goal.getX() - this.enemies[j].getX()) < (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2))
                    && (Math.abs(this.goal.getY() - this.enemies[j].getY())
                    < (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2))) {
                this.player.die();
                this.goal.die();
                this.stage.setGameOverBackground();
                j = this.numEnemies;
                this.continueGame = false;
            }
            j++;
        }
        try {
// Draw stage
            this.canvasGraphics.drawImage(stage.getCurrentImage(), 0, 0, null);
// Draw player
            this.canvasGraphics.drawImage(player.getCurrentImage(),
                    this.player.getX() - (this.player.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2),
                    this.player.getY() - (this.player.getCurrentImage().getHeight() / 2), null);
// Draw enemies
            for (int i = 0; i < this.numEnemies; i++) {
                this.canvasGraphics.drawImage(this.enemies[i].getCurrentImage(),
                        this.enemies[i].getX() - (this.enemies[i].getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2),
                        this.enemies[i].getY() - (this.enemies[i].getCurrentImage().getHeight()
                        / 2), null);
            }
// Draw goal
            this.canvasGraphics.drawImage(this.goal.getCurrentImage(),
                    this.goal.getX() - (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getWidth() / 2),
                    this.goal.getY() - (this.goal.getCurrentImage().getHeight() / 2), null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
// Draw everything.
        this.gameGraphics.drawImage(this.canvas, this.borderLeft, this.borderTop, this);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        this.gameGraphics.drawString("FPS: " + String.format("%2d", (int) (1000000000.0 / (end - start))),
                this.borderLeft + 50, this.borderTop + 50);
    }

    public Goal getGoal() {
        return this.goal;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
// Below, the setKey method is used to tell the Player object which key is
// currently pressed.
// The Player object must keep track of the pressed key and use it for
// determining the direction
// to move.
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            this.player.setKey('L', true);
        }
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            this.player.setKey('R', true);
        }
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            this.player.setKey('U', true);
        }
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            this.player.setKey('D', true);
        }
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            this.continueGame = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
// Below, the setKey method is used to tell the Player object which key is
// currently released.
// The Player object must keep track of the pressed key and use it for
// determining the direction
// to move.
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            this.player.setKey('L', false);
        }
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            this.player.setKey('R', false);
        }
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            this.player.setKey('U', false);
        }
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            this.player.setKey('D', false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
    }
}
```

My Player Class (subclass):

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Player {

private BufferedImage imageRunning;
private BufferedImage imageOver;
private BufferedImage imageCurrent;
int valx = 500;
int valy = 100;


public Player(int valx, int valy) {

    try {
        this.imageRunning = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/HUS/Desktop/Assigment222/images/player-alive.png"));
        this.imageOver = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/HUS/Desktop/Assigment222/images/player-dead.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.imageCurrent = this.imageRunning;
}

public BufferedImage getCurrentImage() {
    return this.imageCurrent;
}

public void setGameOverBackground() {
    this.imageCurrent = this.imageOver;
}

public void performAction() {
    if(Player.setKey('D', true) == true) {
        this.valx += 2;
    }
    else if(Player.setKey('D', false) == false) {
        this.valx = 0;
    }
    return;
}

public int getX() {
    return valx;
}

public int getY() {
    return valy;
}

public void die() {
    return;

}

public static boolean setKey(char c, boolean b) {
    return b;


}

}
```

Comment: As a recommendation, it's probably not the player's responsibility to deal with the movement, but more the "main loops". If, however, you want to the player to do this, then you should be passing in the current "input state" (and probably the boundaries the player can move in), but I again, I don't believe that this is the domain the player

Comment: As an extension, don't store the "input state" in the `Player`, store it in a "input model" - this really should be independent of the `Player` (because you might want to add mouse input later, for example)

Comment: @MadProgrammer hey thanks for taking the time to reply, i should of also mentioned above that this is work handed to me and i was told not to change anything in main class, also the objective of this game is to have the player move towards the goal (part im working on now) using key events while the enemy class chases the current position of the goal. Also im not that knowledgeable in java and i dont really understand what u meant by passing in the current "input state"  or storing input model, although i will make sure to read up on those now and get back to you with hopefully good news

Comment: @MadProgrammer also i only need the arrow keys for this game, no mouse or controller will be supported. Also feel free to ignore this last part if u are busy but mind linking me to examples or tutorials of input model or input state? cant seem to find much java related or its just that idk what im looking for exactly haha. Once again thank you for taking the time to reply

Comment:  hand it back ... okay, seriously. `performAction` doesn't have enough information or perform bounds checking (how to do you know when you've moved to far?). But, `setKey` should be storing the state of the specified `char`, probably in a `Map` or `Set`.  `performAction` should then check to see if the `Map` or `Set` contains a specific character (and in the case of `Map`, it's active/`true`) and execute the required action

Comment: hmm i think im starting to get what your saying. if i understood ur telling me to store the current state of a key from key event int a Map or Set, while using peformAction to actually change the values when the key is pressed? and sorry, when i said it was handed to me it was given to me by a friend, i told him i was intreseted in trying to program simple stuff on java and he gave me an old assignment of his to try out and solve. i was only given main class and told to make sub classes without changing the main class and that it was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when `keyPressed` or `keyReleased` is called, they will, in turn, call `Player.setKey`.  When this gets called, you store the state.

For example...

```
public class Player {

    //...

    // I really, really, really don't static been used this way, it
    // has a bad code smell about it...
    public static Set<Character> inputState = new TreeSet<Character>();

    //...

    public static void setKey(char c, boolean b) {
        if (b) {
            inputState.add(c);
        } else {
            inputState.remove(c);
        }
    }

}
```

So, all this really does is either adds the `char` to the `Set` or removes it.  Because `Set` guarantees uniqueness, we don't need to care if the key has already been pressed.

Then when `performAction` is called, you check to see if the input is in the `Set` or not and take appropriate action...

```
public void performAction() {
    if (inputState.contains('U')) {
        // Going up
    } else if (inputState.contains('D')) {
        // Going down
    }
    //... other inputs
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks i just gave this a shot but i seem to be getting an syntax error with "inputState.add(c);" the ".add" seems to be the error. Any idea's on why this may be occurring? or anything u could recommend me to read/google to find out more about set? btw this is the error message: http://prntscr.com/ji0pbp

Comment: Did you define inputState before hand? Are you using java.util.Set

Comment: Yes i believe i did it right, here is a screen shot just incase: http://prntscr.com/ji0sw9

Comment: What version of Java are you using? (Ps I tested the code before I posted it to make it would work the way I think it should)

Comment: hmm i have Java 8 Update 151 (64-bit) and Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 151 (64-bit). Im also using Eclipse Java Oxygen (re downloaded it 4 months ago so its fairly new) btw thank you for testing to code, means a lot to know that this is the right code i just need to get it to work on my end :P

Comment: when i search JDK on my hard drive i see JDK15 and JDK16, not sure if they are the versions

Comment: It should be `public static Set<Character> inputState = new TreeSet<Character>();` not public static Set<Player> inputState = new TreeSet< Player >();`, `Character` is actually a inbuilt type

Comment: Oh im so dumb -.- my bad. Thank you for all your help, i really mean it iv been at this for a while now and this part had me stuck for a while. Its all working now thank you so much <3